# Django not passing data to views on POST request

Tags: python, jquery, html, css, django

I've created a drop-down menu that is supposed to pass data to a view that'll help filter a queryset. However, it doesn't seem like the data is actually being passed to the view. Below is the relevant code I've written.

template.html

```
<!-- Query based content for dropdown menu -->
<form method="POST" action="{% url 'property-selected' %}" id="property-select">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <select class="dropdown-content" onchange="this.form.submit()" name="property-select">
        {% if current_user_meters %}
            <option disabled selected> -- select an option -- </option>
            {% for meter in current_user_meters %}
                <option class="dropdown-menu-option" value="{{meter.id}}">{{meter.name}}</option>
            {% endfor %}
        {% else %}
            <option>You don't have any meters</option>
        {% endif %}
    </select>
</form>
```

views.py

```
def property_selected(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':

        selection = request.POST.get('property-select')

        current_user_groups = Group.objects.filter(
            id__in=request.user.groups.all()
        )
        current_user_properties = Property.objects.filter(
            groups__in=current_user_groups
        )
        current_user_meters = Meter.objects.filter(
            meter_id__in=current_user_properties
        )

        selected_meters = Meter.objects.filter(name=selection)
        selected_meter_data = MeterData.objects.filter(
            name=selection
        ).order_by('date')

        return render(request, 'properties/property-selected.html', {
            'current_user_meters': current_user_meters,
            'selection': selection,
            'selectected_meters': selected_meters,
            'selected_meter_data': selected_meter_data,
        })
```

For the querysets in the views file, the `selection` variable doesn't seem to be getting anything, which is where I want the data from the POST request to go. I want the data from the POST request to go there so my `selected_meters` and `selected_meter_data` queries will work as intended.

Answer (score 2):

The values in the property-select options are IDs, but you are trying to filter MeterData by name with those values. Either filter by id, or use the name attribute as the option values.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! However, this doesn't help solve why the selection variable doesn't seem to be posting. The problem occurs before any of the filtering/querying happens. I know this because I made a test template have a response if the selection variable exists when the page loads, and the template didn't respond correctly.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. When the page first loads, it is not a POST, so where is that value supposed to be coming from?

Answer (score 0):

You need to either use a form to ingest your data (thereby providing cleaning and validation) or access request.body instead of request.post, and then parse it for yourself.

From the documentation, emphasis mine (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.POST):

> HttpRequest.POST¶ A dictionary-like object containing all given HTTP
>   POST parameters, providing that the request contains form data. See
>   the QueryDict documentation below. **If you need to access raw or
>   non-form data posted in the request, access this through the
>   HttpRequest.body attribute instead**.
>
> It’s possible that a request can come in via POST with an empty POST
>   dictionary – if, say, a form is requested via the POST HTTP method but
>   does not include form data. Therefore, you shouldn’t use if
>   request.POST to check for use of the POST method; instead, use if
>   request.method == "POST" (see HttpRequest.method).

I'd recommend passing the request into a form. It gives you some nice functionality down the line, and lets you avoid parsing request.body for yourself, even if it's an extra step.

Comment: This all seems irrelevant. Where does OP want to access non-form data? They just want the data from the "property-select" element, which is submitted in the POST data. There is no need to "parse request.body" themselves here at all.